# Concurrently Dequeueing an item

Tags: c#, concurrency, parallel-processing

Assume we have two threads working with a method that execute below:

```
while(true){

    if(Queue.Count() <= 0){
        wait();
    }

    object anObject = Queue.Dequeue();
}
```

Now the problem occurs when Queue has one element init, Thread 1 is about to execute Queue.Count line, Thread 2 about is on Queue.Dequeue() and execution priority is on Thread 1.

As this situation occurs, Thread 1 will throw an exception because, Queue.Count() will return 1 and it will try to dequeue an object from an empty queue. How can I handle this? What is the best solution if I want to dequeue safely? Should I use syncronized or lock something?

Best regards,
Kemal

Comment: Consider taking a look at TPL DataFlow library. Good for keeping you sane with queuey thready async stuff! Here's a primer: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14782

Answer (score 2):

The best solution, assuming you are using .NET 4.0 or higher and **really need a queue**, is to switch to using [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) and it's TryDequeue method.  ConcurrentQueue is thread safe.

That said, it looks from your code snippet like what you are really looking for is a thread safe producer/consumer queue.  In that case, use the [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287085) class and it's Take method:

```
while(true){
    // This will block until an item becomes available to take.
    // It is also thread safe, and can be called by multiple 
    // threads simultaneously. When an item is added, only one
    // waiting thread will Take() it
    object anObject = myBlockingCollection.Take();

    // do something with anObject
}
```

Comment: When using a `BlockingCollection` in this context you can also use the `GetConsumingEnumerable()` method to replace the whole loop with a `foreach` loop, which reads better and even also supports a better end condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use thread safe queue [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx).

or if you don't want to use it

```
    while (true)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(lockObj);
        try
        {
            if (Queue.Count <= 0)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(lockObj);
            }

            object anObject = Queue.Dequeue();
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
        }
    }
```

or if using `lock`

```
    while (true)
    {
        lock(lockObj)
        {
            if (Queue.Count <= 0)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(lockObj);
            }

            object anObject = Queue.Dequeue();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well actually I'm trying to understand the logic behind it, is there any good documentation about how we can do it regardless of programming language

Answer (score 0):

Lock the queue before accessing it.

```
lock (Queue) {
    // blah blah
}
```

**EDIT**

```
while(true){
    lock (Queue) {
        if (Queue.Count() > 0) {
            // Dequeue only if there is still something in the queue
            object anObject = Queue.Dequeue();
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: Using lock in this case might be inappropriate solution because we lock it and if the Queue.Count returns  0, thread will start to wait to be signaled and the other threads will wait because of lock implementation so deadlock will occur ??! :)

Comment: @kkocabiyik: What is `wait()` doing exactly? Why don't you dequeue only if `Queue.Count() > 0`?

Comment: Wait() actually stands for calling semaphore to wait that is bound to different threads. So that a thread signals to other threads back and forth.

Comment: So you already did a sort of `lock` implementation as I understand. It seems that only some `if (Queue.Count() > 0)` before dequeueing is missing then.

Comment: In addition to this, dequeueing only if Queue.Count() > 0 is not what I need. When you look at my case, I'm trying to realize what happens if thread 2 at 4th line and thread 1 is at 2 line and thread 1's turn. When thread 1's turn, Queue.Count() will return 1, and thread 2 will execute dequeue, and lastly thread 1 tries to dequeue empty queue

Comment: @kkocabiyik See my edit please. Does it have the behavior you are trying to get? If not, I'm afraid I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Hmm It is close i guess, but the thing is i want all consumer threads go to sleep until a new item enqueued into queue and signaled back. It will cause to deadlock in this case :)

Comment: @Otiel your second example is probably logically correct, but will consume serious CPU time while the queue is empty.  Any thread that calls it will be permanently sent into a hot tight loop until there is an item to dequeue.  You need some waiting and signalling in there too.

Comment: @ChrisShain True! @kkocabiyik Doing `while(true)` is probably a bad idea in the first place. It would be better to use a timer in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

**Producer**

```
public void Produce(object o)
{
  lock (_queueLock)
  {
    _queue.Enqueue(o);
    Monitor.Pulse(_queueLock);
  }
}
```

**Consumer**

```
public object Consume()
{
  lock (_queueLock)
  {
    while (_queue.Count==0)
    {
      Monitor.Wait(_queueLock);
    }
    return _queue.Dequeue();
  }
}
```